# Popup doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-popup

I want to show popup window.

Here the jQuery Mobile page:

```
<div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="centered-butons">
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align: center" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div></div>

    <div id="myPopup" data-role="popup" data-theme="a" data-corners="true" data-transition="none" data-position-to="origin" data-aria="disabled">
      <p>This is a simple popup.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on anchor the popup don't show up.

Comment: Looks like an external popup, you have two options 1) Place it inside page div 2) if you want to access the same popup from any page (external popup) you need to initialize it manually `$(function () { $("#myPopup").popup(); });`.

Comment: No I need to display popup from the same page.It worked fine until I updated JQM library from 1.2.0 to 1.4.5.

Comment: Then go with first option.

Comment: any idea why it worked before I updated my JQM library?

Comment: Newest version is totally different than old ones.

Comment: @Omar, I placed all in div tag (you can see update above) but the result is the same, popup not displayed.Any idea why it not displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look to the [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1fov5cd9/) I made, it works fine.

I think that your problem can be that your jQuery JS library version is not compatible with the new JQuery Mobile after updating to 1.4.5.

Try changing the jQuery version. It worked for me with

- jquery-1.8.3.min.js
- jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

I hope this helps you!

Comment: I tried and worked fine with: jquery-1.8.3.min.js
and jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js

Comment: No, it does not work with jQuery 2.2.1. Look this one with 2.2.1 https://fiddle.jshell.net/1fov5cd9/1/ and this one with 1.8.3 https://fiddle.jshell.net/1fov5cd9/ . Only the second case works,